# Design: Exposing user interface behaviour to external systems

Tags: integration

I'm working on a web application (Java EE backend) which contains a fairly complex input modal. This input modal allows the user to capture data, but it has a bunch of (JavaScript) restrictions, such as mandatory fields, fields only being available if a specific value is entered, etc.

I have to expose this functionality to external systems and allow them to submit this data to my server. These external systems can be both web or client based (but I can assume that the clients will have internet access). My first thought is to provide some kind of definition of the fields and stuff like mandatory to these systems through services, and have them render the input modal however they want. This has been met with resistance though, because the types of fields and restrictions will likely change quite a bit during the next few months of development. These external systems have different deployment timelines, and for this to work we'll have to firstly duplicate all the logic handling these restrictions across all systems, and secondly synchronize our deployments.

An alternative which has been proposed is to have the external systems call my modal through standard HTTP and render it either in an iframe or in an embedded rendered. This solves all of the previous complaints, but it leaves me feeling a little uneasy.

Are there any alternatives we are not thinking of? Maybe some kind of UI schema with existing render libraries for the different platforms? What are your thoughts on the second proposal, any major concerns or is this the "best" solution?

Edit: To clarify, I'll of course still perform backend validation regardless of the frontend decision, as I can't just trust the incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints that you mention (mandatory fields etc.) really have nothing to do with the user interface. You are also right that it is not a good idea to have your backend render web content.

Your first proposal sounds like a good idea, here's how I would solve the issues you mentioned:

- Do all the validation on the backend and send a model object to the client, representing the current state of the UI (field name, type, enabled/disabled, error message etc.).
- Keep the client as dumb as possible. It should only be responsible for rendering the model on a window / webpage. Whenever a field is changed and it requires validation, submit the model to the backend for validation and get back a new model to be displayed. (You could optimize this by only returning the fields that changed.)

Doing it this way will keep your validation logic in one place (the backend) and the clients rarely need to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I agree with what your saying, I believe the main critiques would be: (a) there are some things which can't be restricted to the backend (such as field types, fields being made available on specific values being selected, auto-completion of some fields based on other values) and (b) this approach would be slower/less user-focussed than one which provides immediate feedback without the need for a server round trip.

Comment: @Zecrates: "Fields being made available on specific values being selected" -- this can be solved with the model I proposed, when a value is selected, you can make a callback (eg. AJAX request) to the backend service and retrieve the new fields. You can do the same for auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

I have been faced with same issues in several previous projects. Based on this experience I can honestly say that server-side validation is the thing you will likely have to implement to avoid rubbish being committed from client side regardless if it comes from GUI or other third party system via API. You can choose one of available validation frameworks, I used [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) and think it is well, or you can implement your own one. On the other hand client side pre-validation, auto-completion and data look up are the solutions you should have to make human users happy. Do not consider about code duplication, just make your system right way from the business point of view.